# Can acrylic concrete patch be drilled into?

Tags: concrete, brick

Can acrylic concrete patch be drilled into? I am using it to fill in some holes in a brick with holes in it where I need to drill into the brick itself and into the area where the patch will be. How long should I let it cure?

Comment: Are you installing an anchor in the patch? Normally, concrete is considered "green" unless it has cured for 28 days or more.

Comment: I am installing a concrete anchor that will go into brick and the end of the anchor will be in the area with concrete patch.

Comment: The information I have on anchors recommends waiting at least 7 days before setting an anchor in new concrete. Especially an expansion anchor. The patch may cure faster, but without a recommendation from the manufacturer I would wait at least a week.